# Is there any way for an Accessibility service to detect when the user is in the launcher or app drawer?

Tags: java, android

If you have an accessibility service that detects events like this:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) { //Called whenever the accessibility service gets an accessibility event

    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
        if (event.getPackageName() != null && event.getClassName() != null) {
            //Component can be an activity, service, BroadcastReceiver, ContentProvider
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName( //Component can be an activity, service, BroadcastReceiver, ContentProvider
                    event.getPackageName().toString(),
                    event.getClassName().toString()
            );

            ActivityInfo activityInfo = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(componentName, 0);

            boolean isActivity = activityInfo != null;

            if (isActivity) {
                Log.i(TAG, "packageName for this activity is " + event.getPackageName().toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't actually know what the package name for the launcher is on many devices. Does it have a package name or something else that can be detected in an accessibility service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find what packages are launchers by looking for the "home" activity:

```
PackageManger pm = getPackageManager();
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

List<ResolveInfo> launchers = pm.queryIntentActivities(homeIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);

String packages[] = new String[launchers.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < launchers.size(); i++) {
    packages[i] = laycnhers.get(i).activityInfo.packageName;
}
```

Do this when you accessibility service initializes, than check if the package for the accessibility event is in the array.

Normally, there should be only one such package, but if the user installed 3rd party launcher or the OEM included optional launcher there may be more.

Comment: Awesome. I have just one question: Will this package name always be different from other android UI package names? I only want to detect when the user is in the home screen or app drawer, not when the user is sliding down the notifications or something like that.

Comment: @purchaseTest usually the notification bar is part of the SystemUI not the launcher (home) package. But a phone OEM could change this. I don't know if any of them do. You may need to perform a more in depth analysis, like checking the window type or position. Depending on what you are actually attempting to accomplish, you might want to consider a different approach. Neither the launcher nor the app drawer are special windows.

Comment: I would have been able to distinguish the launcher by the fact that it's supposed to be an activity, but I found that some android devices don't report the home launcher as an activity. What else can distinguish the launcher or app drawer?

Comment: @purchaseTest nothing. The launcher is just an app. How it is implemented is up to whoever implements it. Take Xiaomi for example - they have a launcher version with no app drawer. because they wanted to copy Apple. The `Intent` I showed you is what is sent when the user hits the home button. What answers is up to the phone maker... I am curious - in the launchers where the home screen is not an activity, what is it?

Comment: I don't know. I just found on some user devices that it's not an activity but I don't have access to the devices.

Comment: Hey sorry just one more question, is there an alternative to `PackageManager.MATCH_ALL`? It requires a min API of 23

Comment: @purchaseTest I believe if you put 0 in the `flags` parameter it will do the job on older versions, but I never tested this. I see no other suitable flags in the `PackageManager` documentation.